# bash script for searching a string already occupied in the textfile

Tags: bash, shell

I want to input  a string through command line to bash script and output to that string to a  text file with current system time as follows.

outputLog.txt

```
name1 = Tue Jan  20 14:00 19 IST 2012
name2 =Tue Jan  20 14:05 19 IST 2012
name3 = Tue Jan  20 14:20 19 IST 2012
name4 =Tue Jan 20 14:45 19 IST 2012
```

I use the following bash script to obtain the output above

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1 = $(date)" >>/root/Desktop/scripts/outputLog.txt

In command line 
[root@localhost desktop]# ./myscript.sh name1
```

Is there any possible way to search the name entered through command line is already found in generated output text file?if found update the current system time of that name string

in command line we enter

```
[root@localhost desktop]# ./myscript.sh name1
```

name1 is already  occupied in the outputLog.txt. I want to output the the text file as

```
 name1 = Tue Feb  21 14:00 19 IST 2012(todays current system time)
    name2 =Tue Jan  21 14:05 19 IST 2012
    name3 = Tue Jan  21 14:20 19 IST 2012
    name4 =Tue Jan  21 14:45 19 IST 2012
```

How can i update that name string with current system time.

Comment: I have a feeling that you're re-implementing the `logger(1)` command.

Comment: Being logged in as `root` is widely regarded as a very bad idea. Just sayin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 fgrep "${1}" /YOUR/OUTPUT/LOG &&
     sed -i "/${1}/ s/.*/${1} $(date)/" /YOUR/OUTPUT/LOG ||
     echo "${1} $(date)" >> /YOUR/OUTPUT/LOG
```

might work for you. *Note* that it fails, if your `nameN` can contain any `/`.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly.But one issue is i have to update the text file with another string if the entered string is not contain in the text file.how it is possible?

Comment: The line continuations are not necessary as long as &&/|| are the last tokens on the line.

Comment: @chinchu The above script updates the log file (in place) if `${1}` occurs in it (and only the line(s) when it occurs). If it's not in it, and you want to write something else, just edit the `echo...` line.

Comment: This too should anchor the match so that you can use Jan, May, Sun etc as the `name` field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep -v` to remove an existing entry for the given username before adding the new timestamp.